# jQuery slidedown and reveal first 3 children with varied height

Tags: jquery

It sounds like such a easy task but I am finding this very hard to get this working correctly due to images loading after the script and hidden children. I keep getting different heights each time I load the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/ek5Uf/

```
$("h2").click(function(){
    var $wrap = $(this).parents(".wrapper");
    $wrap.find(".scroller").height(function(){
        var height = 0;            
        $wrap.find(".scroller > li:lt(3)").each(function(){
            height += $(this).outerHeight(true);
        });
        return height;
    }).slideDown();
});

$("h2").eq(0).click();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do without setting any height at all?

Comment: But I have more than 3 children, so have a overflow-x showing a scrollbar. If there was no height this wouldnt work

Comment: I see. You only want to show the first 3 list items with the `ul` overflow-y then.

Comment: Yep each list item can have a different height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but this should be a sturdy solution for setting the scroller's height to the height of its first 3 `li` items:

```
$("h2").click(function(){
    var $wrap = $(this).closest(".wrapper");
    $wrap.find(".scroller").height(function() {
        var lis = $("> li:gt(2)", this).detach(),
            ret = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        $(this).append(lis);
        return ret;
    }).slideDown();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ek5Uf/5/)
I've edited your fiddle slightly to give different sizes to the images for better testing.

I tried making a solution with `.position()` but it gave weird results, so `detach` the `li`s > 2, get the `.scroller`'s `outerHeight` with solely the first 3 `li`s and reattach the detached `li`s is the best solution I can imagine.

Comment: Wicked thanks, thats perfect. Been trying to get this working all morning